# Can I get help on the circuit diagram?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

So I recently ordered and received the [Adafruit heating pad](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1481) (10 × 5 cm<sup>2</sup>). And I'm looking over the website to see if I can find a circuit diagram for how to use it since I don't have other components.

I have:

- A power source
- A potentiometer

I'm trying to use the potentiometer as a variable resistance to change how hot the heating pad gets but i don't know how to wire everything together. It would be better for me to see how its all wired together with a circuit diagram but any input is appreciated.

Comment: You will get more responses if you include the part numbers of your components, ideas that you have, things you've tried, relevant schematics, and what your goals are.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use a pot by itself to control the power into the mat. You would need a high wattage rheostat and that is likely far too expensive. A pot would need to control some form of electronic regulator in order to control the power to the mat.

At 5 volts the mat will draw 1 amp of current. You can use a linear regulator to control the current through the mat by adjusting the voltage to the mat. A linear device will dissipate up to 2.5 watts. It would be simple.

What would be more efficient would be a pulse with controller. The pot would set the on percentage.

This controller should do the power control for you. One of the pictures shows how it would be hocked up.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-Motor-Speed-Governor-PWM-Stepless-Speed-Controller-Regulator-LED-Dimming-5V-16V-10A-Ultra-High/32900670848.html

Comment: Just to make sure. What you are saying includes the fact that I am using this pad?           
                                                                                
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sparkfun-electronics/COM-11289/1568-1798-ND/6569361&?gclid=Cj0KCQiAurjgBRCqARIsAD09sg97H2Yd3bLZolnwcWtyKjxsG1sWtQ5ifMJUuz9XJ-nworm9RbhESbAaAu76EALw_wcB                                                                              (Yes later on I would aim to go bigger but for right now I'm just trying to get a hang of using it)

Comment: This one is 60% of the current of the one you linked to in your question. But it still is the same problem with the same solution. A pot is very rarely used to limit power. Most often it is used to take an input voltage and provide an output voltage that varies from the maximum input down to zero. The resultant voltage is then fed into an amplifier or controller that deals higher power. This is what happens with a stereo system. The signal is attenuated with the pot and that then feeds the amplifier. The amplifier handles the power required by the speakers. I will continue in the next comment.

Comment: Sometimes higher wattage pots are used in series with the load. For example a pot used in a speaker that is used to attenuate the output of the high frequency speaker. The power content of the high frequencies is much lower than what the low frequency driver must deal with, so a special wire wirewound pot with a mid power handling capability can be used. But for that application the range of operation minimal. Maybe decreasing the signal down to half of the original, never off.

Comment: For that kind of application a pot like this can be used in series with the speaker. https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/ohmite/RES25RE/RES25RE-ND/824038 Once again, I suggest you use a proper controller as it is a cheaper and more effective option.

Comment: Thanks @Rudy that's helpful information. One quick thing though. Do you think I could get me heating pad to work if I used a transistor?

Comment: Yes you can. I will add a schematic in the following question.

Answer (score 0):

With the pot turned so the wiper is at the top the transistor base will be at 5 volts and the emitter will be at about 4.3 volts. There will be a minimum 0.7 volt loss. When you turn the pot down the load voltage will also follow (but at 0.7 volts lower). The transistor will need some form of heatsink in order to keep it within it's temperature rating.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm okay thanks I am going to look up these components order them and then try them out thanks for the help @Rudy :)

Comment: You still would be better off with a circuit like I suggested in my first answer. The above works but it isn't ideal. It can't give you full power, because of the base to emitter voltage drop.

Comment: The pot rotation in the above circuit would not give you a a great feeling as to the amount of power/heat. At the low end there would be more rotation with little to no effect. But it is a minimal simple circuit.